Is a thread execution slower when it's running inside a dll instead of a .exe?
I have a Visual Studio 2022 project where I'm creating a C++ DLL. This DLL exposes a function to start threads.
Subsequently, I have a C# DLL, also in Visual Studio 2022, which acts as a wrapper. It uses P/Invoke to include all functions from the C++ DLL and then exposes them as class methods.
When I call the method exposed by my C# DLL to start the thread, from a project using the C# DLL, the thread runs at a certain speed (I monitor the speed from Task Manager -> Performance -> Network Kbps, as the threads capture images from a camera and stream the flow over HTTP).
The problem is that this speed is lower compared to when I modify the C++ DLL project from .dll to .exe, create a test main, and launch the thread. (In this case, it has higher speed.)
I need my DLL to expose the maximum speed achieved when started from a C++ main.
If the thread code under the DLL is the same in both cases, but in one case it runs in a .dll file and in the other case directly within the same executable, could this influence? How can I achieve this?
Sample main code with correct performance:
int main()
{
    CCamFlir cam1 = CCamFlir(TCModel::A70, "10.0.0.102");

    cam1.OnConnect();
    cam1.OnSetLivePort(7001);
    cam1.SetTransmission(1);
    cam1.SetEmissivity(1);
    cam1.SetAutoRange(false);
    cam1.OnLoadPalette(TCPalette::IRON, 18, 40);
    cam1.OnSetZoom(1.0, 0, 0);

    cam1.setCamBeforeStream();
    cam1.StartThermalStream();

    cam1.OnSetLiveThreadFrequency(30);
    cam1.OnSetAcquisitionTCFrameRate(FrameRateAvailable::HZ30);

    cam1.OnDrawRoiSquare(6, "", 50, 50, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, FontType::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
        2, 50, 50, 55, 55);

    cam1.StartHTTPServer(60000);
    int conta = 0;
    while (true)
    {

        //if (cv::waitKey(33) == 27) // Exit when ESC is pressed
        //  break;
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        //conta++;
        //if (conta == 10) {
        //  cam1.OnSetRange(LOW);
        //}

    }
    return 0;

}

Slow thread code:
void UpdateCurrentFrame(CCamFlir* camInstance)
{
    try
    {
        camInstance->isTerminateUpdateCurrentFrameThread = false;
        high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
        high_resolution_clock::time_point end;
        int frames = 0;

        high_resolution_clock::time_point fps_timer = high_resolution_clock::now();
        camInstance->m_rawImageLive = Image::Create();
        std::atomic<bool> shouldTerminate(false);
        

        while (!camInstance->m_terminate)
        {
            start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            high_resolution_clock::time_point iteration_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

            try
            {
                camInstance->m_rawImageReceive = camInstance->m_cam->GetNextImage();
                if (!camInstance->m_rawImageReceive->IsIncomplete() || camInstance->m_rawImageReceive->GetImageStatus() == 0)
                {
                    camInstance->m_rawImageLive->DeepCopy(camInstance->m_rawImageReceive);
                }
                
            }
            catch (std::exception& ex)
            {
                std::string e = ex.what();
                camInstance->m_status = DISCONNECTED;
            }
            end = high_resolution_clock::now();

            long duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
            std::chrono::milliseconds durataMilliseconds(duration);
            camInstance->m_iterationTime = durataMilliseconds;

            frames++;

            camInstance->m_rawImageReceive->Release();

            auto elapsed = duration_cast<seconds>(end - fps_timer).count();

            if (elapsed >= 1) {
                camInstance->m_effectiveFrameRate = static_cast<double>(frames) / elapsed;

                fps_timer = high_resolution_clock::now();
                frames = 0;
            }

        }
        camInstance->isTerminateUpdateCurrentFrameThread = true;

    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::string eccezione = ex.what();
        camInstance->m_status = DISCONNECTED;
        camInstance->isTerminateUpdateCurrentFrameThread = true;

    }
}


thread start :
bool CCamFlir::StartThermalStream()
{
    try
    {
        m_cam->BeginAcquisition();
        if (m_getNextImageThread.joinable())
            m_getNextImageThread.join();
        m_getNextImageThread = std::thread(UpdateCurrentFrame, this);

        if (m_getLiveImage.joinable())
            m_getLiveImage.join();
        m_getLiveImage = std::thread(GetLiveImage, this);

        if (m_updateROIValue.joinable())
            try
            {
                m_updateROIValue.join();

            }
            catch (const std::exception& ex)
            {
                std::cout << ex.what();
            }
        m_updateROIValue = std::thread(UpdateROIValue, this);

        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {       
        return false;
    }
}



exposed method from c++ to c#

    __declspec(dllexport)bool CamFlir_StartThermalStream(CCamFlir* pCam) { return pCam->StartThermalStream(); }

c# class exposed from c# dll

  [DllImport("lib\\DriverFlir.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern bool CamFlir_StartThermalStream(IntPtr cam);

  private IntPtr PtrCam { get; set; }

 public void StartStream()
 {
     CamFlir_SetCamBeforeStream(PtrCam);
     CamFlir_StartThermalStream(PtrCam);
 }


main c# , with efficiency problem :
namespace CameraFlir
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            string ip = "10.0.0.102";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ip);

            CameraFlir cam1 = new CameraFlir(DriverFlir.TCModel.A70, byteArray);
            cam1.Connect();
            cam1.Transmission = 1;
            cam1.Emissivity = 1;
            cam1.SetAutoRange(true);
            cam1.SetPalette(DriverFlir.TCPalette.IRON);
            cam1.SetZoom(1, 0, 0);

            cam1.StartStream();
            cam1.LiveFps = 30;
            cam1.AcqusitionTCFrequency = DriverFlir.FrameRateAvailable.HZ30;

            cam1.StartHTTPServer(65000);

            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

Network performance (correct, in terms of the number of images captured per second from the camera) when executed directly in C++:
Slow network performance when called from C#
I expect that the speed is influenced by the calling language change, but once the thread is launched, shouldn't the thread itself be the same? Shouldn't it be unaware of its caller and function the same way?

No an exe or a dll will not affect a threads speed. Are you sure your compiler settings (optimizations) are the same for the exe and the dll?

What is difference is not whether the code is in an exe or dll. What is different is that one version is running only the code, and the other is running the code and has is running the CLR. (Also, both versions have a thread consuming 100% CPU which is low hanging fruit.)

@RaymondChen I was also thinking about all the extra marshalling that needs to be done. In general I would say don't mix technologies like this.

camInstance->m_rawImageLive->DeepCopy(camInstance->m_rawImageReceive); copying whole images is probably also not helping.  Basically when you have performance issue you need to profile your code to understand your bottleneck (it is not always where I or you think it is). Another option to get more control is to write C++/cli wrapper instead of using dllimport

Another side note : do NOT use high_resolution_clock, but use steady_clock for time measurements.

I would totally think the difference is P/Invoke and the marshalling. You should be able to test that by creating a single DLL in C++ that has one single entry point and does everything that the multiple calls from C# do. It should be obvious then.

Yes, I know that calling with P/Invoke makes it slower than native code, but once a thread is started, shouldn't it run at the same speed, whether it was launched by an external program or by a native program?

@marcoPP - That's what you should test.
